# SharePoint 2010 VHD outgoing e-mail error

Tags: email, networking, sharepoint-2010

I use the SharePoint 2010 VHD from Microsoft and my e-mail doesn’t seem to work and I’m rather new to SharePoint 2010.
I tried to do the following. In SharePoint Designer I created a Workflow and of the action involved sending an email to the initiator of the workflow.

I received the following error message in my workflow history:
“The email message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.”

In my Central Administration I have the following mail settings:

Outbound SMTP Server: demo2010b.contoso.com

From Adress: administrator@contoso.com

I also started the Exchange Server in Hyper-V but still didn’t work.
I didn’t change anything in the Settings.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test basic SMTP and network connectivity between the two VMs? Assuming telnet client is installed on demo2010a, try (from demo2010a):

```
telnet demo2010b.contoso.com 25
```

or even

```
ping demo2010b.contoso.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ping gives me an error. I have an internal network which is recommended in the virtual maschine detup
1. IP address: 192.168.150.6
2. Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
3. Default gateway: (leave blank)
4. Preferred DNS server: 192.168.150.1